# python - generate dataframe from output without knowing columns keys

Tags: python, dataframe

In case I want to create dataframe from my CLI output but I don't know the columns keys in it,
All I know is where is the raw that the keys ends at (starts from raw number 0) and I know the seperator between those keys (`\s+`).

In such scenario Is there quick and nice way to find (generate) columns keys for dataframe from output?

For example:

```
                                                                                 MODIFIED

CORE SERVER         ACTIVE                         PASSIVE                       PACKAGES

------------------  ------------------------------ ----------------------------- --------

cs010               1.9.2.0-2+auto166              1.9.2.0-2+auto146             no
```

It's should generates the following keys list: `CORE SERVER , ACTIVE , PASSIVE , MODIFIED PACKAGES`

Comment: have you tried the pandas `read_csv` method?

Comment: You should put example code showing what an input _could_ look like. Also, if you have tried anything yet you should put that as well.

Comment: Hi , I've added example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand correctly, you could split the string input containing all the column names separated by white space and then build a dictionary using list comprehension and then make na empty DataFrame from that.

```
import pandas as pd

string="""
                                                                                MODIFIED

CORE SERVER         ACTIVE                         PASSIVE                       PACKAGES

------------------  ------------------------------ ----------------------------- --------

cs010               1.9.2.0-2+auto166              1.9.2.0-2+auto146             no
"""
string = string.split("-")[0]

col_names ={name:[ ] for name in re.split(r"\s\s+", string) 
    if name is not ""}

df = pd.DataFrame(col_names)
print(col_names)
print(df)

# with output below:
{'MODIFIED': [], 'CORE SERVER': [], 'ACTIVE': [], 'PASSIVE': [], 'PACKAGES': []}
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [MODIFIED, CORE SERVER, ACTIVE, PASSIVE, PACKAGES]
Index: []
```

The documentation for regular expression splits is here: [re.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) if you wanted to use regular expression.

Because you have lines output that could double up in lines but appear to have hyphens that indicate the column size you could use something similar to:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

string="""
                                                                                 MODIFIED
CORE SERVER         ACTIVE                         PASSIVE                       PACKAGES

------------------  ------------------------------ ----------------------------- --------

cs010               1.9.2.0-2+auto166              1.9.2.0-2+auto146             no
"""

rows = [row for row in re.split(r"\n|\r", string)]
for row in rows:
    if "---" in row:
        # get all of the splits below columns
        indices = [i for i,j in enumerate(row) if j.isspace()]
        # After you find the column width stop checking rows.
        break

indices.insert(0, 0)
matrix = [ ]
for row in rows:
    # from your output, hyphens show where headers stop
    if "---" in row:
        break
    matrix.append([row[i:j] for i,j in zip(indices, indices[1:]+[None])])

n = (len(indices))
col_names = [""]*n

for i in range(n):
    for row in matrix:
        col_names[i] += row[i]
    col_names[i] = col_names[i].strip()

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[c for c in col_names if c is not ''])
print(df)

# with output:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [CORE SERVER, ACTIVE, PASSIVE, MODIFIED PACKAGES]
Index: []
```

This code isn't the most efficient thing ever but gets the job done and doesn't require the addition of many function.

Comment: There is a problem with your output becuase MODIFIED PACKAGES and CORE SERVER should be one phrase (one slot inside the list)

Comment: @ms_stud thank you for finding my mistake, I updated the code first example is assuming one line of text output and the latter example is specific to your example code above. It does make some assumptions made so please let me know if they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

I created my own functions that generate it and it works.

```
def auto_generate_dataframe_columns(output, raw_separtor="---", col_seperator=r'\s{2,}'):
    """Automatically generate dataframe columns.

    :param output: output for generating columns from
    :param raw_separtor: keys raw seperator symbol
    :param col_seperator: columns raw separator symbol (default separator is double or more spaces)
    :return: list with generated keys in case of success otherwise None
    """
    if output is None:
        return None
    keys_lines_list = []
    pattern = re.compile(col_seperator)
    for line in output.splitlines():
        if raw_separtor in line:
            break
        curr_line = line.lstrip()
        curr_line = pattern.split(curr_line)
        if not is_line_empty(curr_line):
            curr_line = [x for x in curr_line if x]
            keys_lines_list = merge_two_lists(keys_lines_list, curr_line)
    return keys_lines_list


def merge_two_lists(list1, list2):
    """Function for merging to lists to one list
    :param list1: first list item
    :param list2: second list item
    :return: merged list
    """
    max_len = list2.__len__() if [list1.__len__() < list2.__len__()] else list1.__len__()
    rev_new_list = []
    for index in range(max_len):
        index1 = list1.__len__() - index - 1
        index2 = list2.__len__() - index - 1
        if index1 < 0:
            rev_new_list.append(list2[max_len - index - 1])
        elif index2 < 0:
            rev_new_list.append(list1[max_len - index - 1])
        else:
            rev_new_list.append(list1[list1.__len__() - index - 1] + " " + list2[list2.__len__() - index - 1])
    return rev_new_list[::-1]


def is_line_empty(line):
    """Function for checking if line is empty

    :param line: given line
    :return: True if line is empty otherwise False
    """
    if not line or (len(line) == 0) or (len(line) == 1 and line[0] == ""):
        return True
    return False
```